# Focus only after rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am trying to add a new input field and setting focus to the new input field on click of a button. The input field is generated but I can't get the focus to go to the new input field. Only after a second click will the focus be set. Can someone explain why this won't work, or how I can make it work?

```
var oInp1 = new sap.m.Input({value:"123",width:"50%"});
oInp1.placeAt( "content" );

var oBtn1 = sap.m.Button( {
  text:"Next",
    press:function(){
      oInp2.setVisible(true);
      oInp2.focus();
    }
} );

oBtn1.placeAt( "content" );

var oInp2 = new sap.m.Input({value:"abc", width:"50%", visible:false });
oInp2.placeAt( "content" );
```

Answer (score 1):

After you set the focus on inp2 some background rendering will take the focus. Here is a dirty workaround which should work. You simply wait 200 ms(normally all rendering should be done) and then request the focus on inp2.

```
var oInp1 = new sap.m.Input({value:"123",width:"50%"});
oInp1.placeAt( "content" );

var oBtn1 = sap.m.Button( {
  text:"Next",
    press:function(){
     var oInp2 = new sap.m.Input({value:"abc"});
      oInp2.placeAt( "content" );

      jQuery.sap.delayedCall(200, this, function() {
        oInp2.focus();
      });

    }
} );

oBtn1.placeAt( "content" );
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Have you heard of any proper way to do it by now?

Answer (score 0):

```
var oInp1 = new sap.m.Input({value:"123",width:"50%"});
oInp1.placeAt( "content" );




var oBtn1 = sap.m.Button( {
  text:"Next",
    press:function(){
     var oInp2 = new sap.m.Input({value:"abc"});
      oInp2.placeAt( "content" );
      oInp2.focus();
    }
} );

oBtn1.placeAt( "content" );
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The result is still the same. Focus is only set to the second input field after clicking the button twice. I am looking to click the button and have a new input field with focus on it.